# Is the employee-paid premium on a health insurance plan that is shared with a non-dependent tax deductible?

Tags: united-states, taxes, tax-deduction, health-insurance, premiums

My health insurance premium for just me is $0. If I add my domestic partner, however, the premium goes up to $190. I know I have to account for imputed income, on the basis of the additional employer-paid contribution to the premium, but am I allowed to deduct the full $190 pre-tax under the health insurance category?

Comment: Sorry—should have clarified. This is in the United States. And the DP is not a dependent for tax purposes.

Comment: Are you asking if the full $190 should be "pre-tax" (meaning not count toward your taxable income on your paycheck) or if you can deduct it when you file your taxes? You can't do both.

Comment: @DStanley: The latter. I'm wondering if I can deduct the $190 from my gross income, pre-taxes.

Answer (score 2):

Both the employer and employee (including dependents) get tax deductions for employer-provided health insurance. Your portion ($190) should appear in the pre-tax area of your paystub. Feel free to confirm with your payroll department.

Comment: This is a little too broad of an answer, in many situations health coverage costs for non-married partners (and potentially their children) are not tax deduct-able in either federal or state contexts.  This is, however, 100% correct in situations of marriage and legally adopted children.

Comment: Even if the health insurance dependent is not a tax dependent, Nick's first stop should be the payroll department to ask if the $190 premium will be a before-tax item. If the answer is yes, I don't think Nick needs to hit the law library to get into the details. Just accept what the employer says, if the employer says that it's pre-tax.